# How to replace a character in the string only giving its index?

Tags: python, string

Im making hangman and i want to put the blank and if he give the correct letters i want to put the correct letter to its correct index blanks this is my code

```
guess = "code"
howmuch = len(guess)
times = "_" * howmuch
blank = times
print(blank)
answer = input("what letter: ")
if answer in guess:
    change = guess.index(answer)
    blank[change] = answer
    print(blank)
else:
    print("wrong")
```

TypeError = "str" object does not support item assignment

Pls give me the solution of this ill just add this to my hangman file this is the only problem to make my hangman program

Comment: can you share your error message  or example of wrong result?

Comment: Might be easier if you use a mutable data structure like a list instead of a string.

Comment: Also, please, provide [mre]. `If` is not `if` and this code would not run at all. Also note that `str.index()` will return the index of first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this might be converting it to list and then joining the list. This can be done by:

```
a = 'Hello'
lst1 = []
for i in a: lst1.append(i) # or use lst1 = list(a) as suggested by @buran
# Code to replace here, use replace function
a = ''.join(lst1)
```

This is just a sample

Another way is to break the string at that index and then concatenating the new character with the replaced string:

```
a = 'Hello'
index = 1
character_to_replace_with = 'a'
final_str = a[:index]+character_to_replace_with+a[index+1:]
```

Comment: `list(a)` is enough to convert str to list. Not sure what you think this `a = i.join('')` would do

Comment: @buran thank you I didn't know of this method to convert. Also, that was a typo, it is supposed to be `lst1.join('')` so thank you for pointing that out too

Comment: It should be `''.join(lst1)`